# How to calculate percentage when old value is ZERO

Tags: math

I need the logic for the following situation. I am clueless in doing this.

> Consider for **January** I have **10$** revenue and for **February** I have **20$** revenue.

My ***growth*** would be `((20-10)/10)*100% = 100%`

> If I have **0$** revenue for **March**.

Then my ***growth*** would be `((0-10)/10)*100 % =-100 %`. Should I call this as negative percentage? (I know its deflation)

Going one step further,

> If now I have  **20$** revenue  for **April**.

How can I calculate the ***growth*** now?, sure the following formula is wrong, `((20-0)/0)*100 %= ?????`

My basic questions are

1. Is there a better solution to find growth rate, other than the one above?
2. If I use the aforementioned formula, should I take some value as reference? or this is wrong also?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not a programming problem.  First figure out what you want to do, then SO will help perfect the code to implement your desires.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I know to implement in program ... i need logic thats it...

Comment: Are you suggesting logic isn't part of programming? I think you mean it's not a **coding** problem. It is a programming problem.

Comment: *the right way to display the results of a calculation where the denominator is 0 is not a programing decision*

Comment: Right. And knowing what is and isn't a programming decision is a *very* important part of programming.

Comment: @mcwyrm: Unspecified behaviour is never a programming decision. If it is an important omission then you send back the spec and ask for it to be specified. If it isn't then you just throw an exception which you assume will never get seen. If it comes up a lot then it was clearly important in which case go back to option 1. Programming is (very broadly) about taking a set of rules and putting them into a programming language. Working out what the rules are is never a programming decision.

Comment: I should also note that often a programmer is expected to fill in gaps in the spec with common sense but when doing that they aren't acting as a programmer, they are writing the spec.

Comment: @Chris The process you describe (identifying and correctly handling unspecified behavior) is an important part of the work programmers do ('programming').

Comment: @mcwyrm: I think we have to disagree there. Just because a programmer does something it doesn't mean it is programming. As a case in point the above question needs no code, no programming expertise and can be done not in front of a computer. Sure, a programmer might end up doing it but I don't think that is hugely important to whether it is programming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're required to show growth as a percentage it's customary to display `[NaN]` or something similar in these cases. A growth rate, on the other hand, would be reported in this case as $/month. So in your example for `April` the growth rate would be calculated as `((20-0)/1`.

In any event, determining the correct method for reporting this special case is a user decision. Is it covered in your user requirements?

Comment: so you telling if the denominator is '0' then i replace it with 1??? right??? did i get it???

Comment: No. If the denominator is '0' then the result of your calculation is not a number and needs to be handled separately.

If, on the other hand, you want to report growth*rate* then you should use a different calculation. Specifically, you should divide the difference in $ (revenue, profit, expenditures, whatever) with the difference in time (hrs, days, months, whatever).

Comment: ...but (and this is very important) the *right* way to display the results of a calculation where the denominator is 0 is not a programing decision. It's a user decision. No one here can tell you the right way to do it; ask your users.

Answer (score 56):

This **is** most **definitely** a **programming** problem. The problem is that it cannot be programmed, per se. When P is actually zero then the concept of percentage change has no meaning. Zero to anything cannot be expressed as a rate as it is outside the definition boundary of rate. Going from 'not being' into 'being' is not a **change**  of being, it is instead **creation** of being.

Comment: I like the phrase "Going from 'not being' into 'being' is not a change of being, it is instead creation of being." this means alot :)

Comment: definitely Shakespeare of programming language !

Answer (score 16):

There is no rate of growth from 0 to any other number. That is to say, there is no percentage of increase from zero to greater than zero and there is no percentage of decrease from zero to less than zero (a negative number). What you have to decide is what to put as an output when this situation happens. Here are two possibilities I am comfortable with:

1. Any time you have to show a rate of increase from zero, output the infinity symbol (∞). That's Alt + 236 on your number pad, in case you're wondering. You could also use negative infinity (-∞) for a negative growth rate from zero.
2. Output a statement such as "[Increase/Decrease] From Zero" or something along those lines.

Unfortunately, if you need the growth rate for further calculations, the above options will not work, but, on the other hand, any number would give your following calculations incorrect data any way so the point is moot. You'd need to update your following calculations to account for this eventuality.

As an aside, the ((New-Old)/Old) function will not work when your new and old values are both zero. You should create an initial check to see if both values are zero and, if they are, output zero percent as the growth rate.

Answer (score 10):

How to deal with Zeros when calculating percentage changes is the researcher's call and requires some domain expertise. If the researcher believes that it would not be distorting the data, s/he may simply add a very small constant to all values to get rid of all zeros. In financial series, when dealing with trading volume, for example, we may not want to do this because trading volume = 0 just means that: the asset did not trade at all. The meaning of volume = 0 may be very different from volume = 0.00000000001. 
This is my preferred strategy in cases whereby I can not logically add a small constant to all values. Consider the percentage change formula ((New-Old)/Old) *100. If New = 0, then percentage change would be -100%. This number indeed makes financial sense as long as it is the minimum percentage change in the series (This is indeed guaranteed to be the minimum percentage change in the series). Why? Because it shows that trading volume experiences maximum possible decrease, which is going from any number to 0, -100%. So, I'll be fine with this value being in my percentage change series. If I normalize that series, then even better since this (possibly) relatively big number in absolute value will be analyzed on the same scale as other variables are. Now, what if the Old value = 0. That's a trickier case. Percentage change due to going from 0 to 1 will be equal to that due to going from 0 to a million: infinity. The fact that we call both "infinity" percentage change is problematic. In this case, I would set the infinities equal to np.nan and interpolate them.

The following graph shows what I discussed above. Starting from series 1, we get series 4, which is ready to be analyzed, with no Inf or NaNs.

[image]

One more thing: a lot of the time, the reason for calculating percentage change is to stationarize the data. So, if your original series contains zero and you wish to convert it to percentage change to achieve stationarity, first make sure it is not already stationary. Because if it is, you don't have to calculate percentage change. The point is that series that take the value of 0 a lot (the problem OP has) are very likely to be already stationary, for example the volume series I considered above. Imagine a series oscillating above and below zero, thus hitting 0 at times. Such a series is very likely already stationary.

Comment: One caveat I like to add is that this strategy works best if you do not have multiple zeros in a row. If you have, then you will get multiple -100s in a row,  which will not make sense because going from one -100 to the next is essentially 0% change, and not -100%.

Comment: this seems pretty helpful, since the very minor change doesn't make significant impact, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can add 1 to each
example
New = 5;
old = 0;

(1+new) - (old+1) / (old +1)

5/ 1 * 100 ==> 500%

Comment: What if Old is -1?

Comment: There are some serious parenthesis/order of evaluation problems in the above.

Comment: What if New = 0.1?

Comment: Same thing 0.1/1 x 100 ==> 10%

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to consider.

If your growth is 0 for that month, it'd be 0 in change from 0. So it is meaningful in that sense. You could adjust by adding a small number, so it'd be change from 0.1 to 0.1. Then change and percentage change would be 0 and 0%.

Then to think about case where you change from 0 to 20. Such practice would result in massive reporting issues. Depending on what small number you choose to add, eg if you use 0.1 or 0.001, your percentage change would be 100 fold difference. So there is a problem with such practice.

It is possible however if you have a change from 1 to 20, then the %change would be 19/1=1900%. Here the % change doesn't make too much sense when you start off so low, it becomes very sensitive to any change and may skew your results if other data points are on different scale.

So it is important to understand your data, and in this case, how frequent you encounter 0s and extreme numbers in your data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be (new minus old)/mod avg of old and new
With a special case when both val are zeros

Answer (score 0):

```
function percentChange(initialValue, finalValue) {
    if (initialValue == 0 && finalValue == 0) {
        return 0
    } else if (initialValue != 0 && finalValue != 0) {
        return (finalValue / initialValue) - 1
    } else {
        return finalValue > initialValue ? 1 : -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `float('inf') * new_value`.
That would be make it better when comparison as comparison with `float('NaN')` will always return `False` except `!=` as it is doesn't match with any value.

Answer (score 0):

To interpolate, for the month between:
month2=((month3-month1)/2) + month1

It's tempting to just add 1 to your zero value, and roll on, but that will make anything with a ratio/rate abnormally huge, so don't do that.

Comment: check to see if the old reading is equal to zero, if it is then add 1 to each

Answer (score -1):

use below code, as this is 100% growth rate in case of 0 to any number :

```
IFERROR((NEW-OLD)/OLD,100%)
```

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: No, it isn't a 100% rate. It's an infinite rate. When you have other numbers that are truly 100% rates using this method would be extremely misleading. Honestly, it's misleading without any other data. As was stated above you cannot mark a percentage changed for a new creation.

Comment: I find this to best solution I had in this matter! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

When both values are zero, then the change is zero.

If one of the values is zero, it's infinite (ambiguous), but I would set it to 100%.

Here is a C++ code (where `v1` is the previous value (old), and `v2` is new):

```
double result = 0;
if (v1 != 0 && v2 != 0) {
  // If values are non-zero, use the standard formula.
  result = (v2 / v1) - 1;
} else if (v1 == 0 || v2 == 0) {
  // Change is zero when both values are zeros, otherwise it's 100%.
  result = v1 == 0 && v2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
result = v2 > v1 ? abs(result) : -abs(result);
// Note: To have format in hundreds, multiply the result by 100.
```