# What is the correct way to calculate percentage increase/decrease between two numbers using Decimal.js?

Tags: javascript, decimal, percentage, decimal.js

**Desired Behaviour**

Show percentage increase/decrease of `new_value` in comparison to `old_value`, showing negative indicator when there has been a decrease, and 4 decimal places (with trailing zeros if necessary).

**Actual Behaviour**

*Good*
If `old_value` is `38.1200` and `new_value` is `19.0600` result is `-50.0000`

*Not so good*
If `old_value` is `0.0000` and `new_value` is `1.0000` result is `Infinity` (I expect the result to be `100.0000`.  **Edit**: I now realise that there is no such thing as a percentage increase from `0` to anything, per posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32023791/1063287)).

**What I've Tried**

```js
var old_value = new Decimal(0.0000);
var new_value = new Decimal(1.0000);
var difference = new_value.sub(old_value).dividedBy(old_value).times(100).toFixed(4, 7);

// without using Decimal.js, the equation above would be:
// (new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100

$(".result").text(difference.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/7.3.0/decimal.min.js"></script>


<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: I suggest you to handle it with an if condition

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming the equation is correct, it was just the `Infinity` result that threw me, so here is solution to "handle" the issue:

```js
var old_value = "38.1200";

if (old_value === "0.0000") {
  // show an infinity sign or something
  $(".result").text("HI!!");
} else {
  old_value = new Decimal(old_value);
  var new_value = new Decimal(19.0600);
  var difference = new_value.sub(old_value).dividedBy(old_value).times(100).toFixed(4, 7);

  $(".result").text(difference.toString());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/7.3.0/decimal.min.js"></script>

<p class="result"></p>
```