# Javascript calculate profit of sale from day to day?

Tags: javascript, math

i am tryin to calculate profit percentage from day to day , for example :

yesterday i sold 10 items , today i sold 5 items , so the percentage must be -50% .

I've managed to make the progress but i believe i still missing something in my calculation .

My table snapshot :
[image]

when the sold items of past day is 0 the progress become infinity .

here is my javascript code :

```
  var class_name = ( parseFloat(row.total_sold)  > parseFloat( row.prev_total_sold ) ? `success` : `danger` ) ;
      class_name = ( parseFloat(row.total_sold)  == parseFloat( row.prev_total_sold ) ? `primary` : class_name) ;
      class_name = ( row.prev_total_sold == null ? `primary` : class_name) ;
    
  var percentage = ( ( (row.total_sold - row.prev_total_sold) / row.prev_total_sold) * 100).toFixed(1);

  return  `<span class="badge badge-light-${class_name} ">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-trend-up text-${class_name}" style="padding-right : 5px"></i> 
                  ${percentage}%
            </span>`
```

Row query :

**prev_total_sold** = is the value of sold items from past day

**total_sold** = is total sold items of current day

the question is : is my calculation good for the requirements ? and why i am getting infinite value when today sold is 0 !

Comment: So whats your question? Why it became infinity? That's the math. There is no `x` such that `0 * x = y` with `y <> 0`

Comment: my question is in the title of my question , which is ` calculate profit of sale from day to day?` to check with experts is my calculation is good and why i am getting infinite value

Comment: Your calcualations are fine. It's just, that from `0` to `x` cannot be assigned any percentage, because that would mean it fulfilled the equation `0 * x = y` which mathematically can't be ...  What would be your expected value for a sales increase from 0 to 10?

Comment: Why would you think `+500%` is correct? +500% means, the new value is six times the original value (ie `y = 6 * x`). That's not the case here because `0 * 6` is still `0` and not `5` That's basic math ...

Comment: @KooiInc Sorry: But your math is just wrong: Why on earth would a decrease from 5 to 0 be `-80%` instead of `-100%`??? Or why would a increase of 0 to 80 be also `80%`???That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @KooiInc Now instead of -80% you give -83.3% for 5 -> 0. How does this make any more sense than 80? The correct value is *100* and nothing else. And no, there is no number that can correctly express the percentage of increase from 0 to something else. Be it 8000, be it 24000 or be it 999999999999999999. Every single one of them is just wrong ...  OP's calculation generally is just fine. Just for the one particular case where the denominator is `0`, he needs to assign a special value (like `infinity`) but not a number, because there is just no number that can express that fact.

Comment: @derpirscher: fine. Unlinked. Suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: @KooiInc See for instance my answer ... The simple answer is: *You cannot assign a percentual increase from 0 to x (with x != 0)*

Comment: @derpirscher [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48735491/58186) is interesting (gist: it depends on (the user interpretation of) the data). I've rewritten the function in my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-774zfv?file=index.js) snippet with your comments and this in mind.

Comment: @KooiInc As I already said OP's calculation is totally fine. Except for one special case when there was increase from 0 to something else ... In this special case, any percental increase in form of a *number* is per se (in a strict mathematical sense) wrong ... And you have to decide what to display ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be a mathematical problem: how many times do you have to multiplicate 0 to get 5? The answer is infinity.

My suggestion here is to check if `prev_total_sold` is 0 then use a default value like `+100%`.

Modified code:

```js
var percentage = row.prev_total_sold ? ( ( (row.total_sold - row.prev_total_sold) / row.prev_total_sold) * 100).toFixed(1) : '100.0';
```

Comment: 100% is definitively even "more wrong" than infinity. Because an increase of 100% has a *very clear* semantics, ie the sales doubled and that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting infinity, because of the underlying math. Assigning a percentage for a growth from `0` to `y` (with `y > 0`) would mean there is some `x` such that the following equation is fulfilled

```
0 * x = y
```

And there can't be such `x` because `0 * something` is always zero.

Displaying `infinity` is the next best thing that happens when you divide by zero in javascript. Other languages may throw an exception. If you want to display any other special value instead of `infinity`, you should check if `prev_total_sold === 0` first before dividing ...

```
var percentage = prev_total_sold === 0
  ? (total_sold === 0 ? "0.0" : "some default value")
  : (((row.total_sold - row.prev_total_sold) / row.prev_total_sold) * 100).toFixed(1);
```

Comment: you still didn't give solution for my question , how i can get 500% instead of infinite ?  and the calculation still not good , as if yesterday selling was 50 and today is 40 its giving -20% instead of -10%

Comment: There is no solution for the infinity problem, because that's the way math works ... And why on earth would you expect `-10%` for a decrease from 50 to 40? The absolute decrease is 10, and 10 is 20% of 50, so the decrease is -20%. Maybe you should brush up on your math a bit ...

Comment: my brain is not so good with math i agreed , that is why i asked for help , thanks for your answer , and i will try to find out how to replace infinite with default value , maybe 0 is good